# Excel - my formula needs to incorporate the last filled cell in column

Tags: arrays, excel, excel-formula

I am building a calculator that detects streamflows that falls below a certain flow rate. I have an array formula that takes a column of data, and identifies how many data points in a row fall below a particular threshold (threshold value in C12):

```
{=MAX(FREQUENCY(IF(E23:E12275<C12,ROW(E23:E12275)),IF(1-(E23:E12275<C12),ROW(E23:E12275))))}
```

This formula works, but I want to be able to build in the ability to detect the last row with entered data. In this example, the data set finishes at E12275, but datasets can extend many more rows. If I extend the formula to this:

```
{=MAX(FREQUENCY(IF(E23:E1000000<C12,ROW(E23:E1000000)),IF(1-(E23:E1000000<C12),ROW(E23:E1000000))))}
```

the formula interprets the blank cells (after the last full cell) as zero, and says that they fall below the threshold. This gives me a result of 987725 (1000000-12275)

I have built another formula that detects the bottom row cell address:

```
=ADDRESS(LOOKUP(2,1/(E23:E1000000<>""),ROW(E23:E1000000)),5,1)
```

However I am having trouble incorporating this result into the existing formula. Does anyone have any thoughts on how to do this?

NB: I have also toyed with the idea of building a formula that excludes blank cells, however the actual datasets include blank cells, which should be interpreted as "below threshold"

Comment: Perhaps you could set your data in a `Table`, and then use structured references to return the data column.

Comment: you could use the aggregate function.  using something like aggregate(14,6,row(A:A)/((A:A<low value)*(A:A>0)),1) to find out the row number

Comment: Thanks for your responses guys, I was able to fix this issue by concatenating the row formula with Sheet:Column information, then using INDIRECT to insert that into the array formula. Inelegant, but it works! Cheers :)